# I can't get my snow leopard mac to boot from thumb drive

Tags: boot, usb, mac

I downloaded the iso and made it an img (dmg).  Now the macbook says that it can't recognize the drive, and it doesn't show up for me to boot from system preferences or when I reboot with the option key!

Comment: Close-voters: There is absolutely no reason to think this is about anything but *installing Ubuntu* on a Mac (which requires [the creation of a Mac-style image file](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) as described in the question, and is totally on-topic for Ask Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Do not boot straight from the drive. It would lead you right into a dead end. Use boot camp to partition your hard drive as if for windows, but just install Ubuntu to that partition. To make a proper thumb drive (in case you didn't make it properly), do the following: open disk utiltiy, locate your thumb drive, erase it to fat32, mount the fresh .iso file, drag the virtual drive for the .iso to the source, drag the now erased thumb drive to the destination, and click restore. Now, for booting into it, I don't know much from there because I went hackintosh with my Dell Latitude D620.